# Django Home url set to folder

Tags: python, django

I have an issue where I would like my address (whether local or live) to point to my projects app as my home page, yet every change I make breaks the other URLs. My main site URL patterns are:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("projects/", include("projects.urls")),
    path("blog/", include("blog.urls")),
]
```

I have tried to change the `path("project/", include("projects.urls"))` to `path("", include("projects.urls"))` which breaks the blog index.

my blog has the following pattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.blog_index, name="blog_index"),
    path("<slug:slug>/", views.blog_detail, name="blog_detail"),
    path("<category>/", views.blog_category, name="blog_category"),
]
```

And my projects:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.project_index, name="project_index"),
    path("<slug:slug>/", views.project_detail, name="project_detail"),
    path("project/<tag>/", views.project_tag, name="project_tag"),
]
```

Comment: When you say it 'breaks the blog index', can you please include an error or a stacktrace of what occurs when it breaks? I've used a similar pattern without issue, so perhaps the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: ```
File "/tzujan/django-portfolio-tutorial/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 496, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /blog/
Exception Value: Project matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: The blog var is being sent to the projects view, not the blog:

    def project_detail(request, slug):
        project = Project.objects.get(slug=slug)
     …

        template = project.template
        category = project.blog_category
        posts = Post.objects.filter(categories__name__contains=category).order_by(

Answer (score 0):

The conflict is coming from django not knowing the difference between:

```
http://example.com/blog
```

and

```
http://example.com/(project_slug_called_blog)
```

because they look functionally identical, just being a string.

You could reverse the order of the URLs so that blog is looked for first

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("blog/", include("blog.urls")),
    path("", include("projects.urls")),
]
```

And that should work so long as not projects are called 'blog'

Or, failing that, you can make the project detail view's URL more explicit

```
path("<slug:slug>/view-details", views.project_detail, name="project_detail"),
```

I'd personally go with the second option as it makes the URL more human readable and is likely a more robust solution.

Comment: Thank you @SamSparx, that did it. I added a line to my slugify call to not allow "blog" - I presume that is not best practice but it works!